# Prevent css "content" being applied to specific element

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this in my wordpress css:

```
.widget-area ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
```

Unfortunately I now want to add something to the widget area without that content of ">" being applied...I can't seem to get it. I've tried initial, none, I just dunno what I am doing wrong and I'm not familiar with "content" or inheritance just yet unfortunately.

```
.decent-comments ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: none!important;
}
```

It's the recent comments thing on the right hand side under the tag cloud here:
http://www.nextlevelsmf.com/news/

Comment: It works from here. Maybe a cache problem?

Comment: You don't see this? http://i61.tinypic.com/20jmeex.jpg

Comment: I saw it before. But when I added the CSS through Firebug. It's removed.

Comment: The CSS is already in the file, it's not showing. I still want that top one in there for all the other widgets, just not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is visible because of the incorrect usage of media queries. You can learn more about them here: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

If you want to use the media queries on screen, use `only`

```
@media not all { // Remove the not or use `only screen` or don't use the media query at all
  .decent-comments ul li::before {
    content: initial !important;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'm new to media queries as well ha ha. Getting there slowly!